# Looking for a SASS organiser/ formatter tool

Tags: css, sass

I've looked around and seen various recommendations for a tool to organise/ format SASS, but none of them do what I'm looking for.

I have a SASS file with very messy selectors. I'm looking for something which would organise like so:

```
.a{
}

.a .b{
}

.a > .b{
}

.a .b span{
}
```

becomes:

```
.a{

  //.a .b
  .b{

    //.a .b span
    span{
    }
  }

  //.a > b
  & > b{
  }

}
```

Most of the tools I tried just tidied up indentation or consistency with closing braces and such. DirtyStylesheet.com fails to do anything (some error in console).

Does such a tool exist or do I need to manually trawl through my SASS and sort it out myself?

Comment: Are you looking to organize your code or your output?

Comment: Code, output is going to be minified CSS.

Comment: What IDE are you using? many IDEs have extensions that beautify your code. I use Atom and it works wonders, but I believe most good IDEs have an extension for this

Comment: I'm using Atom, but again, I believe the Beautify stuff only fixes things like indentation, rather than rearranging the whole file with optimal nesting and such

Comment: @DevMan try to install a linter scss at Atom its a start to you learn some practices